# SeqLogo of AA in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am looking for an R package which work similar to SeqLogo von Bioconductor. I know there is WebLogo, but i think it is way over the head for my purpose, which is following:

i have a data.frame in R which looks like this:

```
    1   2   3   4
T   0.2 0.3 0.5 0.0
R   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1
...
all 20 aminoacids
```

So i have for each position (up two 12) a probability that this amino acid occurs at this position. I just want a basic SeqLogo plot from this distributions. 
As far as i know WebLogo needs an alignment of sequences and SeqLogo only allows DNA.

Example:
[image]

Comment: You should at least provide links to image that are similar to what you want. Or the code necessary to produce the other plots. Otherwise we have no idea what these plots look like based on your description here.

Comment: Not an R package, but you could try [Seq2Logo](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/biotools/Seq2Logo-2.0/bin/freq.txt), giving your data in [frequency format](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/biotools/Seq2Logo-2.0/bin/freq.txt).

Comment: @MrFlick I am sorry this a standard plot in bioinformatics, thats why i did not put it in, but i'll update it now!

Comment: @ping My data is already in R and i do much more statistics on it. So using a python program would be very uncomfortable. But i'll have a look. thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally linked the example data twice, the first link should be http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/biotools/Seq2Logo/ I assumed it would be ok for you since you mentioned WebLogo, and they're fairly similar in terms of use.

Comment: Have you checked out the motifStack package from Bioconductor?